# Function to search all worksheets and calculate fields based on a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project to record and view upsells.
This is all being controlled by MSforms.
Each month has its own sheet which all users upsells are posted too.
I have built the calculation to calculate month todate upsells per user, but what I now need for it to do is calculate the year to date figures per user.
The user name will be posted into a variable via the loggin system I have built.
If it helps the sheets that record the upsell are named starting with "ups".
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Public Sub btn_test_Click()

    Dim var_nextline4 As Integer
    Dim var_Allsheets As Variant

    var_YupsN = 0
    var_YpremR = 0
    var_Yhups = 0
    var_ytdRev = 0

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim z As Variant
    z = "a"
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ' do something with worksheet WS
    If Worksheets(WS).Cells(1, 1) = "Associate Name" Then
    var_nextline4 = 2
        'z = "a"

        Do While z <> ""
            z = Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 1)
                If z <> var_associate Then
                    var_nextline4 = var_nextline4 + 1
                Else
                    Me.lsb_upsell.AddItem Cells(var_nextline4, 5).Value


        Select Case Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 10)
                        Case "CYS"
                var_YpremR = Yvar_premR + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 6).Value
                        Case "LDS"
                var_YpremR = var_YpremR + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 6).Value
                        Case "LVK"
                var_YpremR = var_YpremR + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 6).Value
                        Case "LVD"
                var_YpremR = var_YpremR + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 6).Value
                        Case "LVB"
                var_YpremR = Yvar_YpremR + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 6).Value
            Case Else
        End Select

        If var_Yhups < Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 13).Value Then
            var_Yhups = Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 13).Value
        End If
            var_ytdRev = var_ytdRev + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 13).Value
            var_Yforms = var_Yforms + 1
            var_YupsN = var_YupsN + Worksheets(WS).Cells(var_nextline4, 6).Value


            var_nextline4 = var_nextline4 + 1

        End If
    Loop

    End If

        Next WS

            lbl_ytdUpsForms = var_Yforms
            lbl_ytdUpsn = var_YupsN
            lbl_ytdPrem = var_YpremR
            lbl_ytdHups = "£" & var_Yhups
            lbl_ytdRev = "£" & var_ytdRev
End Sub
```

Comment: what is your problem? does your code not work? does it throw an error? be more specific if possible

Comment: I've fixed it now, For some reason the Do While loop did not want too work within the For loop, so I placed the Do while loop in a seperate function and then called that function within the for loop